# Regular Expression to match all or initial part of a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I Am trying to find out a Regular expression, which will match with below criteria.

My String to Match

```
 var txt = "This is Regex";
```

User can enter anything like below

1. "This" -- Valid
2. "Th" -- Valid
3. "This is" --Valid
4. "This is Reg" -- Valid
5. "This is Regex" -- Valid
6. "Tis" -- InValid
7. "is" -- InValid
8. "Reg" -- InValid

So user can **enter part of the Text or Full text**.
If user enters part of text, It should **validate for sequence** and if it doesn't matach with the `txt` sequence then its invalid.

I am looking for solution using jQuery, But even Plain JavaScript also fine.

Just to clarify my requirement I gave above 7 senarios, Its not that only user can enter above 7 (for Ex:- If user Enters "T", then it is alo valid as it is first Character and If user enters only "H" it is invalid, as it is not prceeded by "T"

Comment: jQuery has nothing to do with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you are looking for is `txt.substring(0, subtxt.length) === subtxt`. In other words, does the search string `subtxt` match the beginning of the `txt` string.

```
function match(txt, subtxt) {
    return txt.substring(0, subtxt.length) === subtxt;
}
```

**Test**

```
> txt = "This is Regex";
> ["This", "Th", "This is", "This is Reg", "This is Regex", "Tis", "is",   "Reg"]
    .forEach(function(sub) { 
        console.log('"'+sub+'"', "--", match(txt, sub) ? "Valid" : "InValid"); 
  })

"This" -- Valid
"Th" -- Valid
"This is" -- Valid
"This is Reg" -- Valid
"This is Regex" -- Valid
"Tis" -- InValid
"is" -- InValid
"Reg" -- InValid
```

#### ES6's `startsWith`

In ES6, you could use the new [String#startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method.

In the polyfill given in the above page, they suggest using `indexOf`, as in

```
function match(txt, subtxt) {
    return !txt.indexOf(subtxt);
}
```

and indeed that seems that it could be faster than extracting the leading part of the string and doing a full string comparison.

### But I really wanted a regexp

If for some reason you really want to do this with a regexp, then try

```
var regexp = /^T(h(i(s( (i(s( (R(e(g(e(x)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$/
```

This regexp can be "read aloud" as

> It starts with a 'T' followed by either nothing or an 'h' followed by either nothing or an 'i' followed by either nothing or an 's' followed by....".

You get the idea.

```
function match1(subtxt) {
    return regexp.test(subtxt);
}
```

**Test**

```
> ["This", "Th", "This is", "This is Reg", "This is Regex", "Tis", "is",   "Reg"]
    .forEach(function(sub) { 
        console.log('"'+sub+'"', "--", match1(sub) ? "Valid" : "InValid");  
  })

"This" -- Valid
"Th" -- Valid
"This is" -- Valid
"This is Reg" -- Valid
"This is Regex" -- Valid
"Tis" -- InValid
"is" -- InValid
"Reg" -- InValid
```

#### Creating the regexp programatically

If you want to automatically turn your string into a regexp which behaves the way you want, although this seems completely pointless, you could do

```
function make_regexp(str) {

    function _make_regexp(str) {
        return str && str[0] + "(" + _make_regexp(str.slice(1)) + ")?";
    }

    return RegExp("^" + _make_regexp(str) + "$");
}

> make_regexp("This is Regex")
/^T(h(i(s( (i(s( (R(e(g(e(x()?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$/
```

Comment: The *RegExp* version does not anchor the expression to the start of the string.

Comment: Also, the *make_regexp* function would be much more efficient without recursion. Consider using split and join: `return str.split('').join('(') + (new Array(str.length).join(')?'));`

Comment: @torazaburo: But this match also "T" and other combination

Comment: @walidtoumi What other combination does it match?

Comment: @torazaburo: it match: `Thi
This i
This is R
This is Re`

Comment: Those are all things which presumably *should* match, based on the logic of the particular examples the OP gave. I highly doubt he intended to match only the specific examples he gave.

Comment: @torazaburo I am looking exactly what you gave in Regex version. Thanks a lot. Could you please add little explanation to "/^T(h(i(s( (i(s( (R(e(g(e(x)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$/"

Answer (score 3):

No need for regex, or even jQuery -- just test and see if whatever the user enters is a substring of your text:

```
function isMatch(userTxt) {
    return txt.indexOf(userTxt) != -1;
}
```

(If the user text doesn't exist in the string, then calling `indexOf` will return -1 since the substring doesn't exist in the string.)

If the string the user enters *must* start at the beginning of `txt`, you could more explicitly check if the index returned is exactly 0:

```
function isMatch(userTxt) {
    return txt.indexOf(userTxt) == 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider userTxt = "This is Regexa"

Comment: @sahbeewah - what about it?

Comment: It should return invalid whilst your solution would return valid.

Comment: @sahbeewah -- Did you try running it? My solution returns `false` if I passed in `"This is Regexa"` since it isn't a substring of `txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
 ^Th(?:is is Reg(?:ex)?|is(?: is)?)?$
```